# How to run a performance benchmark on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: hardware, performance, benchmark

I need to run some sort of performance benchmark to measure how slow my MacBook Pro is (and why)—a 15" MacBook Pro (late 2008) with a  2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor, 4 GB of DDR3 memory, and running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 very, *very* slowly. Most of the tasks I perform (e.g. deleting a file or folder, typing letters, switching desktops, etc) can take more than an unacceptable 10-30s response time. I also have a second, 22" monitor.

Is there any way to measure a MacBook Pro's response time? Is there any free software I could use to run a performance benchmark and understand why it is so slow? I'm running the built-in Activity Monitor, but I have no idea how to diagnose the issue(s).

Comment: still using HHD instead of an SSD this days?

Comment: A benchmark would typically only determine how fast/slow your computer is running compared to other specifications, not (help) determine what's actually wrong.

Comment: I would redirect this inquiry to Apple's Support Communities. Run http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck, include it in your enquiry, and ask the question "Why is my computer running slowly?" rather than seeking benchmark comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would run [Geekbench](http://www.primatelabs.com/geekbench/) on it and then you'll have some actual statistics to make comparisons with and go from there.

I would guess your HDD is the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Dukeatcoding, I just got this benchmark report http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench2/1021668. Any ideas on how to read this?

Comment: http://browser.primatelabs.com/mac-benchmarks look for a comparabel configuration. Steam should be the KPI you should look out for. All in all you really have not a good result here ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same MacBook Pro. Mine was running extremely slow. I installed an SSD hard drive and did a clean install of OS X El Capitan. It runs like a new computer now.

I also upgraded my RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB.  Crucial has a program that will tell you exactly what you need.

But for around $175, you can have it running like new!

Comment: Jep SSD is the key, that was what I meant with "I gues your HDD is the problem"